# Wasm: does anyone support multi-value WASM?

Tags: c, rust, webassembly

Passing multiple values from WebAssembly to Javascript can be harder than it needs to be. Normally, I find that I have to:

1. Setup memory shared between Javascript and WebAssembly.
2. Do the Wasm work to produce the values.
3. Store the values somewhere in the shared memory.
4. Output a memory pointer to Javascript.
5. Have Javascript retrieve the values from shared memory.

Multi-value is a feature of Wasm intended to make this easier, where multiple values can be passed directly from Wasm to JavaScript, eliminating the need to deal with pointers. The steps become:

1. Do the Wasm work to produce the values.
2. Output the values to Javascript.

For example:

```
(module
  (func $multResult (export "multResult")
    (result f64 f64)
    f64.const 1
    f64.const 2
  )
)
```

We directly output 1 and 2.

I can use [Rick Battagline's helpful functions](https://github.com/battlelinegames/wat-wasm) to compile Wasm from WAT (with a [slight fix](https://github.com/WebAssembly/multi-value/issues/18) to properly support the multi-value flag):

`node ./bin/watwasm bugrepro.wat -o newoutput.wasm -O3 --multi-value`

Turning the resulting Wasm compilation back into WAT, we get:

```
(module
 (type $none_=>_f64_f64 (func (result f64 f64)))
 (export "multResult" (func $0))
 (func $0 (result f64 f64)
  (tuple.make
   (f64.const 1)
   (f64.const 2)
  )
 )
)
```

That `tuple.make` command is the secret sauce that makes the function consumable directly in JavaScript. If I write this JavaScript:

```
const fs = require('fs');

const wasmBytes = fs.readFileSync('./newoutput.wasm');

WebAssembly.instantiate(wasmBytes)
    .then(obj => obj.instance.exports)
    .then(exported => exported.multResult())
    .then(res => console.log(res));
```

I can see that `[1,2]` is returned by the Wasm function. Terrific.

I want to be able to do this with higher-level languages than WAT. Do any higher-level languages produce multi-value Wasm?

Answer (score 6):

There are two: Rust and C. Rust seems to produce the smallest `.wasm` file so far.

[TinyGo does not](https://github.com/tinygo-org/tinygo/issues/2512). [AssemblyScript does not](https://github.com/AssemblyScript/assemblyscript/issues/1633). [Grain does not](https://github.com/grain-lang/grain/issues/1456). [SwiftWASM does not](https://discord.com/channels/780838335798706197/802944960881098752/1117367603107737721).

**For Rust**

The below example assumes that you intend to use WebAssembly in a browser. Compiling for WASI (using WebAssembly in an operating system) is slightly different; see [this comment](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/73755). The primary point of WebAssembly is to provide light, fast code in browsers, and how light/how fast depends on whether the WebAssembly goals align with the source language's priorities. The below example assumes that you want your WebAssembly maximally light. (See [here](https://rustwasm.github.io/book/game-of-life/code-size.html) for helpful information on how to reduce `.wasm` size in more complex scenarios.)

1. [Install Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/tools/install).
2. [Install Node](https://nodejs.org/en). Or more likely, [install NVM](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/node-version-manager-nvm-install-guide/), and pick a version of Node compatible with whatever else you have going on.
3. Install Binaryen: `npm install -g binaryen`
4. Add the target `wasm32-unknown-unknown` using `rustup target add wasm32-unknown-unknown`. (WASI uses a different target.)
5. Create a project using `cargo new`, and add this code to `Cargo.toml`:

```
[profile.release]
lto = true
opt-level = "z"
strip = "debuginfo"

[lib]
crate-type = ["cdylib"]
```

6. Write a library that includes a function intended to be used in a WebAssembly context which returns multiple values. Make a file called `lib.rs` and add the following:

```
#[no_mangle]
fn flip(a: u32, b: u32) -> (u32, u32) {
    (b, a)
}
```

7. Apply the following environment variable wherever you intend to run the `cargo build` command: `RUSTFLAGS="-Ctarget-feature=+multivalue -Clink-args=-zstack-size=64000"`. (Implementation details depend on your operating system and command line program.)
   Rundown of the flags:

   *-Ctarget-feature=+multivalue*: tell Rust to enable the WASM multi-value feature

   *-Clink-args=-zstack-size=64000*: tell Rust to use one page of WASM linear memory. (Rust defaults to 16 pages of memory. For a very simple use case like the example, this is wasteful, so reset the memory to use the minimum setting. Browsers allocate 1 page per WASM thread anyway.)
8. You're going to want a release version, not a debug version. In step 5 above, `strip = "debuginfo"` is stripping out the debug information. Besides, the point of the program is to run within the context of a browser, so any debugging/testing should be done by embedding the code within Javascript. Use this command to compile a `.wasm` file: `cargo build --release --target=wasm32-unknown-unknown`
9. Use the `wasm-opt` tool from Binaryen to squash the code more: `wasm-opt -Oz -o [output file name].wasm [input file name].wasm`

Using [this page](https://webassembly.github.io/wabt/demo/wasm2wat/) to convert the `.wasm` into `.wat`, here is the entire program:

```
(module
  (type $t0 (func (param i32 i32) (result i32 i32)))
  (func $flip (export "flip") (type $t0) (param $p0 i32) (param $p1 i32) (result i32 i32)
    (local.get $p1)
    (local.get $p0))
  (memory $memory (export "memory") 1)
  (global $__data_end (export "__data_end") i32 (i32.const 64000))
  (global $__heap_base (export "__heap_base") i32 (i32.const 64000)))
```

Very clean. Not perfect, but just about. At just 239 bytes, the `.wasm` file is smaller than that produced in C.

**For C**

You have to use the Emscripten compiler in a special way. (This is apparently only otherwise mentioned anywhere in [this Twitter entry](https://twitter.com/tlively52/status/1229944658354032640).)

First, build the function in C. For example:

```
typedef struct _nums
{
    int x;
    int y;
} nums;

nums echo(int x, int y)
{
    nums result = {x,y};
    return result;
}
```

This defines a C `struct` containing two `int`s, then defines a function which echoes whatever is sent to it.

It can be compiled with Emscripten as follows:

```
emcc -mmultivalue -Xclang -target-abi -Xclang experimental-mv -Oz -s STANDALONE_WASM -s EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS="['_echo']" -Wl,--no-entry hello.world.c -o bob.wasm
```

Quick breakdown of the flags:

1. `-mmultivalue`: tells Clang to enable multi-value support
2. `-Xclang -target-abi`: tells Clang to target an application binary interface
3. `-Xclang experimental-mv`: enables more multi-value stuff?
4. `-Oz`: tells Clang to produce code aggressively optimized for size
5. `-s STANDALONE_WASM`: tells Emscripten not to produce Javascript glue code that it normally produces
6. `-s EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS="['_echo']"`: tells Emscripten not to optimize away the 'echo' function if it finds no reference to it. This allows you to export the code to Javascript from WebAssembly.
7. `-Wl,--no-entry`: tells Emscripten not to try to make a default entry in the WebAssembly
8. `hello.world.c`: the input C file
9. `-o bob.wasm`: output a file called 'bob.wasm'

This results in this code:

```
(module
 (type $none_=>_i32 (func (result i32)))
 (type $i32_=>_none (func (param i32)))
 (type $i32_=>_i32 (func (param i32) (result i32)))
 (type $i32_i32_=>_i32_i32 (func (param i32 i32) (result i32 i32)))
 (memory $0 256 256)
 (table $0 1 1 funcref)
 (global $global$0 (mut i32) (i32.const 5243920))
 (export "memory" (memory $0))
 (export "echo" (func $0))
 (export "__indirect_function_table" (table $0))
 (export "__errno_location" (func $4))
 (export "stackSave" (func $1))
 (export "stackRestore" (func $2))
 (export "stackAlloc" (func $3))
 (func $0 (param $0 i32) (param $1 i32) (result i32 i32)
  (tuple.make
   (local.get $0)
   (local.get $1)
  )
 )
 (func $1 (result i32)
  (global.get $global$0)
 )
 (func $2 (param $0 i32)
  (global.set $global$0
   (local.get $0)
  )
 )
 (func $3 (param $0 i32) (result i32)
  (global.set $global$0
   (local.tee $0
    (i32.and
     (i32.sub
      (global.get $global$0)
      (local.get $0)
     )
     (i32.const -16)
    )
   )
  )
  (local.get $0)
 )
 (func $4 (result i32)
  (i32.const 1024)
 )
)
```

That produces a lot of boilerplate. The important bits:

```
...
(export "echo" (func $0))
...
(func $0 (param $0 i32) (param $1 i32) (result i32 i32)
  (tuple.make
   (local.get $0)
   (local.get $1)
  )
 )
```

Comment: Rust supports multi-value return! See: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/73755#issuecomment-1574461575

Comment: Sweet! I will rewrite the article in the coming days to describe an example using Rust.

Comment: Great job rewriting this! Just one more note, another reason to compile with `--release` is, certain libraries (like serde_json) just won't compile without it. I'm not sure why!

Comment: Update. I'm not sure if it's fair to say that Rust supports multi-value returns, actually, due to this aformentioned issue with compiling certain popular libraries (like serde_json). My own conclusion (as a CTO trying to hammer out a Rust WASM product) is that it's not ready for prime time. I would not recommend anyone actually use it in production until the underlying issues are fixed. https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/73755#issuecomment-1577586801